# Regular expression is not working

Tags: python, regex, unicode

**I need to remove all the symbols like `{} &+( )" =!.?.:.. / |  » © : >< #  «  ,]  _ - + ; [ ]` including digits from the file.**

```
import codecs
import re
def clean_symbol() :
    symbols = re.compile(r'[{} &+( )" =!.?.:.. / |  » © : >< #  «  ,]  _ - + ; [ ]  % 1, 2,3',flags=re.UNICODE)
    with codecs.open("e.txt","r") as fileobject:
        for line in fileobject:           

            good_words = symbols.sub(" ",line)

            print(good_words)
            with codecs.open("/home/corpus/Clean_tex1t.txt",'a',encoding="utf-8") as out:
                out.write(good_words)
```

This is the code to remove symbol from a Unicode text file  but the code is producing expected results.
Input

```
 «   » 


    _                       _468 60_1");


                 _     "         :1004    :1000;                   ;"
                :1004      :0     ;"
                  "              :0099  ;"
              _   2"         :68          :14                3300    (   12         _   .   )        68   -137  ;"             "           :4   20   5   12  ;"        .   "        
            "
 സര്‍ക്കാര്‍ജീവനക്കാരുടെ ശമ്പളം അറിയാന്‍ ഭാര്യമാര്‍ക്ക് അവകാശമുണ്ട്വിവരാവകാശകമ്മീഷന്‍  

                "       ="_     "             :8  ;"                 
                "       ="_     "               


          "       ="_     "
```

Expected output

```
സര്‍ക്കാര്‍ജീവനക്കാരുടെ ശമ്പളം അറിയാന്‍ ഭാര്യമാര്‍ക്ക് അവകാശമുണ്ട്വിവരാവകാശകമ്മീഷന്‍
```

The code is not working at all. What is the problem here ?

Comment: It is not the last line. It is mixed with symbols

Comment: Your regex basically searches for a literal string `  _ - + ;    % 1, 2,3`, prefixed with one other sign. I don't think this is what you meant to achieve. Can you be more specific about what the regex should and should not do?

Comment: @PeterWood No, The problem is different here, Please check the code

Answer (score 1):

Regex might not be the best suited approach for dealing with your problem, unless you really only want to filter out the specified special characters. 
Slightly different approach, maybe not brilliant but returns the expected result:

```
# coding=utf-8

text = u"<yourcontenthere>"

res = ""
for i in text:
    if ord(i)>255:
        res = res + i
print res
```

This works for your example. (I've tested it.) It filters out all ASCII characters and leaves you with the result you expected.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) module for serious unicode work. Also, matching symbols you want to keep (=whitelisting) is usually easier than removing unwanted characters (=blacklisting). Example:

```
import regex
print ' '.join(regex.findall(ur'[\p{IsMalayalam}\u200D]+', data))
```

This prints what you're looking for. `[\p{IsMalayalam}\u200D]` matches a Malayalam character or the ZWJ symbol.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax inside a character class is very restricted, and has special cases for caret (which signifies negation if it is the first character in the character class), dash (which signifies a range if it is not the first or last character in the character class), and closing square bracket (which signifies end of the character class, unless it is the first character after an optional caret and perhaps a dash).  Customarily, opening square bracket is listed adjacent to closing square bracket to keep them paired.

So your regular expression will have to be refactored to

```
r'[-][{} &+( )" =!?:./|»©:><#«,_\-+;]'
```

excluding duplicates and assuming the character before the plus is not a regular ASCII dash but rather some Unicode character.  (Maybe use hex escapes to disambiguate.  I found I had to backslash it.)

If you want to add numbers, that should be easy.  You also seem to be missing single quote; is that intentional?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    clean_symbol()
  File "/home/akallararajappan/corpus/clean_symbol.py", line 4, in clean_symbol
    symbols = re.compile(r'[-][{} &+( )" =!?:./|»©:><#«,_-+;-]')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/re.py", line 206, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/re.py", line 255, in _compile
    return _compile_typed(type(pattern), pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/functools.py", line 184, in wrapper
    result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
  It gives many erros

Comment: Editing out the minus sign -- which I commented on -- allows my Python to compile it.  I don't get the same error you report.  Backslashing the minus sign also seems to work.

Comment: I am getting same in two versions of python

Comment: @karu I can compile that pattern.

Comment: Remove spaces from the character set and add a multiple space pattern - ```r'[{}&+()"=!?:./|»©:><#«,_\-+;0-9]|\s{2,}'```